# mailto in href: should I add rel noopener,noreferrer?

Tags: html, security, mailto, privacy

Assuming I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.org" target="_blank"></a>
```

As far as I know, for security and privacy reason, best practices tells I have to add `rel="noopener noreferrer"` on every link that goes outside. Do I have to consider a `mailto` link as an external link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within a mail message, I think it won't make any difference. Referrer headers include the URL of the location of the source link - but an email message does not *have* a URL, so I'd expect the referrer header to be empty or absent in that case.

It's not possible to use things like `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` in an email client because they typically don't support any kind of scripting. When you're using a webmail client this might behave differently, but I've not tested that.

Going the other direction, if you have a web page containing the mailto link that gets sent to a mail client, I've never seen a mail client that does anything with a referrer URL, again, because it's not an HTTP client and is not handling an HTTP request, but a protocol hand-off.

Overall setting `rel="noopener noreferrer"` will not harm your links, but I suspect it won't do anything useful or interesting from a functionality or security point of view either.

Answer (score 10):

You can better understand it here: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/

<s>Short answer: no need, since the link doesn't open a new `window` which could (ab)use the `window.opener` issue explained in the link above.</s>

*UPDATE:* As op pointed out - my assumption that a mail client will handle the `mailto:` links was wrong. One could have used `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` to make a web app handle these links (or any other links for that matter). Thus, I would say you should add  `rel="noopener noreferrer"` as originally proposed.

Comment: Thanks. `mailto` opens a new window for me.

Comment: did you use `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` to handle `mailto` links? by default a mail client should be launched.

Comment: My mail client is gmail, i'm on a mac with firefox, and when I click on "mailto" it always open a new tab with gmail.